# Kotlin: String newline not trimmed by trim() function

Tags: android, json, kotlin, encoding, newline

I have two strings retrived from json file (Arabic json files previously parsed from txt files). I use kotlin `trim()` function to remove leading and trailing newlines after parsing from json. The problem is, one of them, say file1, is successfuly trimmed while the other, say file2, is not.

I have thought of the encoding, but never managed to get my way through it. All what I know is json files are most likely encoded from utf-8 source. So I convert both files with Kotlin String function `toByteArray(Charsets.UTF-8).contentToString`:

`file1` always has: [32, 10] as last elements in its bytes array (where newline character should be).

`file2` always has: [32, 10, **-30, -128, -113**] as last elements in its bytes array (where newline character should be).

It sounds like there are additional three byte chracters at the end of the file with the problem (I have no idea what these minus signs stand for).

This is my way to fetch json and create JSONOBject:

```
val file: String = applicationContext.assets.open("poets/${poetID}.txt").bufferedReader().use {
        it.readText()
}

val json = JSONObject(file)
```

here, `${poetID}.txt` is actually json file in asset folder `poets/`.

I have the same application written in Swift with no such problems.

My question is: What are these assitional bytes at the end? Is there a way to check for encoding of a string parsed from json files? Or a way to change the encoding programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The additional character represnts the Right-to-Left Mark. It is a common unicode character in Arabic language.